# Fetch. fulfillRequest return binary data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to use CDP to intercept the request and return bytes so that the user can download it directly, but it seems that the body of Fetch.fulfillRequest only supports base64 encoding and does not support binary data return.

It is expected that the request can be intercepted so that the request can directly download the specified content.

Comment: Simply encode your data in base64.

Comment: Because the data I need to pass is large, I don't want to encode it to base64 again

Comment: Well, the only other way is quite convoluted: patch the target's JS prototypes like XMLHttpResponse.prototype's getter for `response` and spoof the returned value using the data sent via messaging.

Comment: This does not achieve the expected behavior, because when the returned code is not base64 encoding, the request will always be in the pending state, and changing the prototype will not work at this time.

Comment: It's unclear what the "returned code" is and why you can't convert your data to base64, and why changing the prototype won't work in your case.

Comment: Because the binary data that needs to be transferred is huge, errors will occur when converting it to base64.
At the same time, if the data I return is binary, the request will always be pending, so there is no way to hijack this binary data by modifying the prototype.

Comment: 1) How huge is it and what is the exact error? 2) When spoofing the prototype you don't need chrome.debugger to pause the request, you can send the data via messaging to your prototype hook, which will then pass it to the site.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP), when using the Fetch.fulfillRequest method, the body parameter indeed only supports base64-encoded data. This limitation is due to the fact that the response body in CDP is expected to be a base64-encoded string.

However, you can still fulfill the request with binary data by converting the binary data to a base64-encoded string. You can use the btoa function in JavaScript to achieve this conversion. Here's an example:

```js
const { fetch } = require('puppeteer');

async function interceptRequestAndFulfillWithBinaryData(page, url, binaryData) {
  // Intercept network requests
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url() === url) {
      // Fulfill the request with binary data converted to base64
      const base64Data = Buffer.from(binaryData).toString('base64');
      interceptedRequest.respond({
        status: 200,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream', // Set the appropriate content type
        body: base64Data,
      });
    } else {
      interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
  });

  // Navigate to a page that triggers the request
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  // Disable request interception after fulfilling the request
  await page.setRequestInterception(false);
}

// Example usage
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Replace 'url' and 'binaryData' with your actual values
  const url = 'https://example.com/your-file';
  const binaryData = /* Your binary data here */;

  await interceptRequestAndFulfillWithBinaryData(page, url, binaryData);

  // Close the browser after the download is initiated
  await browser.close();
})();
```

In this example, the interceptRequestAndFulfillWithBinaryData function intercepts the specified URL, converts the binary data to a base64-encoded string, and fulfills the request with the base64-encoded data. Note that you should set the appropriate contentType based on the type of data you are serving.

Keep in mind that converting binary data to base64 increases the data size, so it's not the most efficient way, especially for large files. If possible, consider using other means to serve binary data directly, such as setting appropriate headers on your server response to trigger a file download.

For more in-depth learning, and stay up to date on your tech stack, consider [JavaScript Weekly](https://javascriptweekly.com/) and [Web Development Weekly](https://webdevelopmentweekly.beehiiv.com/subscribe).

Comment: Thank you very much, but because I am providing a large file for download within chrome extensions, converting to base64 may cause errors.